# Ruby Appending an hash and saving it in a CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, hash, append

I am learning ruby from a book I got called *The Pragmatic Programmers Guide* and have got to a point where I'm reading and processing things from a *.csv* file. I taken upon myself the challenge of making a small program that opens a *csv* file and then reads all the data, saving it into a hash. This is my code so far:

```
require 'csv'

class NoxReader

phash = {}
  def open
    CSV.foreach('data.csv', headers: true) do |row|
      row.each do |x|
      name, password = line.chomp.split(",")
        phash[name] = password
       end
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to be able to append to that hash and write it back to the *csv* file. I have an idea on how to write it back to *csv*, but it's just appending to the hash via a `gets.chomp` that blows me away. Any help on where to start would be much appreciated.

Comment: so, you are able to edit "phash" but not able to save it as csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you are already appending key-value pairs to your hash. This is what `phash[name] = password` does in your code.

If you want to add the resulting hash of your function `login_prompt` in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180776/how-can-i-store-user-defined-data-in-a-hash) to `phash`, you need to

```
phash.merge login_prompt
```

Comment: thanks man my readers is fine now i studied a little more and eventually got it working. :)